# Powershell Outlook Email Security custom classes

Tags: classes, powershell, enum

This provides custom classes to work with Outlook 2016's email security settings in trust center. Included are some top level functions to list outlook profiles, retrieve the data from a given profile, and to set data into the correct registry key.

This code works as-is but I have some comments for parts that I think could maybe be improved somehow. Any criticism is welcome.

Github repo
https://github.com/timothy-byles/powershell-OutlookES-classes

**Notes:**

- The ESAlgorithmAsn class does not parse ASN1 data. Instead, the binary streams for each algorithm type are stored as byte arrays and
  the resultant stream is generated as an ASN1 stream of sub-streams
- One of the helper functions if FindInArray. This is not only used in the classes but is also useful for error checking or testing.
  If you load existing settings from the current profile and then use FindInArray to compare
  [ESConfig].GetBytes() to the original blob. If no changes are made, both blobs should be identical (ignoring any padding that Outlook
  may have appended
- I found that sometimes Outlook will append padding to config sets. Data generated from these classes will not have that padding.
- These classes provide the ability to remove algorithms from the ASN1 stream. In my testing this did not actually prevent them from
  displaying in email security settings dialog
- It's possible to have an algorithm flag set as the default in an ESAlgorithmAsn object as well as set in the Other* property of the same
  type. This is perfectly safe and the algo duplicate will be removed when generating the resultant stream
- If you have multiple flags set in the default has or encryption property for an ESAlgorithmAsn object when you call GetBytes(), it will
  throw an error and fail to complete
- The thumbprint and hash properties are read-only and will throw an error if you try to set one. Instead use either
  SetSignatureCert or SetEncryptionCert as described below
- Once you load settings into an [ESConfig] object, you are able to manipulate the attached sub-objects and then write the settings back to
  the registry. Eash GetBytes method will call the GetBytes() method of its sub-object, thus saving changes made to said sub-object

```
Usage:

Get-OutlookProfileList
Retrieves a list of Outlook profiles in the current user's list

Get-OutlookESConfig -profileName name
Returns an object of type ESConfig for the given profile. This contains the whole collection of all email security configurations

Set-OutlookESConfig -profileName name -ESConfig [byte[]] binary_blob [-noBackup]
This will save the new data back to the registry key for current user. If a settings key already exists, it will be backed up unless -nobackup is set




[ESConfig] class

property [ESConfigSet[]] Entries
Collection of config sets indexed by int


constructor New()
constructor New($name)

Create a new instance of ESConfig object with a single config set and the name specified or a name of "Default Settings"

method New([byte[]]$blob)
Create a new instance of ESConfig object and import data from the byte array. This byte array is pulled directly from the settings registry key.

method AddEntry([ESConfigSet]$set)
Add a configSet object to the Entries collection. This object can be created using [ESConfigSet]::New('name')

method RemoveEntry([int]$index)
Removes a configset from the collection

method SetDefaultEntry((int]$index)
method SetDefaultEntry([string]$name)
Mark the designated configset as default

method GetLength()
Returns the total length of the byte array that would be created with GetBytes()

method GetBytes()
Returns a byte array of all config sets. This can be written directly to the settings registry key



[ESConfigSet] class

property [string] Name
Name of the config set. This is the same name you would see in email security settings for this set

property [ESConfigOption] Options
This is an enum collection of settings. The only currently known settings are Default 1 and 2 which correspond to
    "Default Security Setting for this cryptographic message format" and "Default Security Setting for all cryptographic messages
    as well as "Send these certificates with signed messages"
It's unknown which default represents which setting. These are labelled Default1 and Default2 in the enum structure
The third option is labelled SendWithMsgs in the enum

property [ESAlgorithmAsn] AlgorithmAsn
This is an ASN1 stream of data. This can be created or loaded using [ESAlgorithmAsn]::New() or [ESAlgorithmAsn]::New([byte[]]$stream) respectively

property [byte[]] SignatureCertHash
This is a read-only binary hash of the chosen signature cert

property [string] SignatureCertThumbprint
This is a read-only string representation of the hash

property [byte[]] EncryptionCertHash
This is a read-only binary has of the chosen encryption cert

property [string] EncryptionCertThumbprint
This is a read-only string representation of the hash


method New()
method New([string]$name)
This creates a new instance of the object with the given name of with a name of "Default Settings" if not provided

method New([byte[]]$blob)
This creates a new instance of the object and imports settings from the provided blob. This blob is the same binary data that exists in
    the ESConfig.Entries collection as a single index

The following 12 methods allow to set/updatea the signature or encryption certifates chosen for this config set
The function will validate that the chosen certificate is available in the current user's cert store unless $Force is set to true
SetSignatureCert([string]$thumbprint
SetSignatureCert([string]$thumbprint, $Force
SetSignatureCert([byte[]]$hash
SetSignatureCert([byte[]]$hash, $Force
SetSignatureCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert
SetSignatureCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert, $Force
SetEncryptionCert([string]$thumbprint
SetEncryptionCert([string]$thumbprint, $Force
SetEncryptionCert([byte[]]$hash
SetEncryptionCert([byte[]]$hash, $Force
SetEncryptionCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert
SetEncryptionCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert, $Force

method GetLength()
Get the length of the byte array that would be output by GetBytes()

method GetBytes()
Generates and returns a byte array of the current config set. This can be added to the [ESConfig].Entries collection using [ESConfig].AddEntry($blob)



[ESAlgorithm] class

enum [CryptAlgs]
AES_256
AES_192
TripleDES
AES_128
RC2_128
RC2_64

enum [HashAlgs]
SHA_512
SHA_384
SHA_256
SHA1

property enum EncryptionAlgorithm
The chosen encryption algorithm for this config set. This uses [CryptAlgs]

property enum HashAlgorithm
The chosen hash algorithm for this config set. This uses [HashAlgs]

property enum OtherEncryptionAlgorithms
Additional algorithms available in the list. This uses [CryptAlgs]

property enum OtherHashAlgorithms
Additional algorithms available in the list. This uses [HashAlgs]

constructor New()
This will create a new instance of this object with defaults set to AES_256 and SHA_512 with the Other* properties null/blank

constructor New([byte[]]$stream)
This will create a new instance and load the data from an existing binary stream

method GetLength()
Returns the lenght of the byte array that would be generated from GetBytes()

method GetBytes()
Returns a byte array of the constructed or reconstructed stream of ASN1 encoded data
```

And the code

```
# Helper functions

# Unless I missed something, PS doesn't provide methods to find index of a sub-array
# This works just like [string].SubString

function FindInArray([byte[]]$source, [byte[]]$find) {
    if ($find.Length -gt $source.Length) { throw 'search bytes are longer than source' }
    $end = $source.Length - $find.Length

    # 0 would be the first array index so -1 means not found
    $iFound = -1
    for ($pos = 0; ($iFound -eq -1) -and ($pos -le ($end)); $pos++) {
        # First find a match for the first element
        if ($source[$pos] -eq $find[0]) {
            # Then check the remaining elements
            $iFound = $pos
            for ($pos2 = 1; $pos2 -lt $find.Length; $pos2++) {
                if ($source[$pos + $pos2] -ne $find[$pos2]) {$iFound = -1; break}
            }
        }
    }
    return $iFound
}


# Very efficient and clever function I found on Stackoverflow, but adapted to PS
# Moved inline as I don't really need a count, I just need to know if there are more than 1
#function CountFlags([enum]$flags) {
#   $count = 0
#   while ($flags) {
#       # I think this would work with a bit shift but I haven't tested that way
#       $flags = $flags -band ($flags - 1)
#       $count++
#   }
#   return $count
#}


# Take a 40 char hex string and return a byte array
# This allows us to accept various types of input to specify a certificate
# Since Windows uses Little-Endian, we have to write it in reverse, then reverse the array

function tp2Hash([string]$tp) {
    $hash = [bigint]::parse($tp, 512).ToByteArray()
    if ([bitconverter]::IsLittleEndian) {[array]::Reverse($hash)}
    return $hash
}


###########################  BEGIN ESAlgorithmAsn custom class  ###########################

[Flags()] enum CryptAlgs {
    AES_256 = 1
    AES_192 = 2
    TripleDES = 4
    AES_128 = 8
    RC2_128 = 16
    RC2_64 = 32
}


# I could not figure out how to assign these during initialization so we'll just do them one-by-one >:-[
# Hashtable for ASN1 encoded encryption algorithms


$CryptAsn = @{[CryptAlgs]::AES_256 = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0B, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x01, 0x2A)}
$CryptAsn[[CryptAlgs]::AES_192] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0B, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x01, 0x16)
$CryptAsn[[CryptAlgs]::TripleDES] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0A, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x03, 0x07)
$CryptAsn[[CryptAlgs]::AES_128] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0B, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x01, 0x02)
$CryptAsn[[CryptAlgs]::RC2_128] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0E, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x03, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x80)
$CryptAsn[[CryptAlgs]::RC2_64] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x03, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x40)


[Flags()] enum HashAlgs {
    SHA_512 = 1
    SHA_384 = 2
    SHA_256 = 4
    SHA1 = 8
}


# Hashtable for ASN1 encoded hash algorithms


$HashAsn = @{[HashAlgs]::SHA_512 = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0B, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x03)}
$HashAsn[[HashAlgs]::SHA_384] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0B, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x02)
$HashAsn[[HashAlgs]::SHA_256] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x0B, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01)
$HashAsn[[HashAlgs]::SHA1] = [byte[]]@(0x30, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x2B, 0x0E, 0x03, 0x02, 0x1A)


# Custom class to handle creating or modifying the ASN1 data that Outlook holds in its email security settings

class ESAlgorithmAsn {
    # It's just one contiguous stream but the 'chosen' algs are moved to the head of each section
    # All encryption entries are listed first then hash entries
    # This is strictly ASN1 encoded data. The accompanying header is handled by the ESConfigSet class

    # Properties
    [CryptAlgs]$EncryptionAlgorithm
    [CryptAlgs]$OtherEncryptionAlgorithms
    [HashAlgs]$HashAlgorithm
    [HashAlgs]$OtherHashAlgorithms

    # Create a new instance with only one of each default and set them to the strongest available
    # This could be moved to a settings section at the beginning of the script
    ESAlgorithmAsn() {
        $this.EncryptionAlgorithm = [CryptAlgs]::AES_256
        $this.HashAlgorithm = [HashAlgs]::SHA_512
    }

    # Is the appropriate way to handle this? Should it be a function like LoadData($stream) ?
    # Maybe we could define a class function and here we would just use that function?
    ESAlgorithmAsn([byte[]]$stream) {
        $CryptAsn = $Global:CryptAsn
        $HashAsn = $Global:HashAsn

        # Currently we use FindInArray to search for each blob in the stream
        # I wonder if it would be more efficient to step through the stream?
        # Need to see what that code looks like since doing it this way loops through the stream quite a few times
        # However, this is very fast as-is and stepping through the stream means needing to parse ASN1 encoded data

        # firstEnum holds the enum of the blob found with the lowest index
        # This becomes the default while others are added to the $this.OtherAlgorithm
        $firstEnum = 0
        $firstPos = -1

        foreach ($enum in [CryptAlgs].GetEnumValues()) {
            $pos = FindInArray $stream $CryptAsn[$enum]
            if ($pos -ne -1) {
                $this.OtherEncryptionAlgorithms += $enum
                if (($firstPos -eq -1) -or ($pos -lt $firstPos)) {
                    $firstPos = $pos
                    $firstEnum = $enum
                }
            }
        }
        $this.EncryptionAlgorithm = $firstEnum
        # We know that Other also includes the default so we can subtract instead of using -band -bnot (see in GetBytes())
        $this.OtherEncryptionAlgorithms -= $firstEnum

        # Forgot to reset these at first and of course, got some unexpected results
        $firstEnum = 0
        $firstPos = -1

        foreach ($enum in [HashAlgs].GetEnumValues()) {
            $pos = FindInArray $stream $HashAsn[$enum]
            if ($pos -ne -1) {
                $this.OtherHashAlgorithms += $enum
                if (($firstPos -eq -1) -or ($pos -lt $firstPos)) {
                    $firstPos = $pos
                    $firstEnum = $enum
                }
            }
        }
        $this.HashAlgorithm = $firstEnum
        $this.OtherHashAlgorithms -= $firstEnum

    }# End constructor ESAlgorithmAsn($stream)

    # I can't imagine this string being longer than 65535 but we're going to code for it anyway
    hidden [uint64]GetDataLength() {
        # Globals aren't available here... who knew...
        $CryptAsn = $Global:CryptAsn
        $HashAsn = $Global:HashAsn

        [uint64]$size = 0
        $allCrypts = $this.EncryptionAlgorithm -bor $this.OtherEncryptionAlgorithms
        $allHashes = $this.HashAlgorithm -bor $this.OtherHashAlgorithms

        # Loop through enum values and see if each flag exists
        foreach ($enum in [CryptAlgs].GetEnumValues()) {
            if ($allCrypts -band $enum) {$size += $CryptAsn[$enum].length}
        }
        foreach ($enum in [HashAlgs].GetEnumValues()) {
            if ($allHashes -band $enum){$size += $HashAsn[$enum].length}
        }

        return $size
    }

    hidden [uint64]GetHeaderLength($dataLength) {
        # Minimum header size
        [byte]$size = 2

        # If the size is 0x80 or greater then the size must be stored in the next n bytes
        # 0x7F would be stored in this byte. 0x80 would be represented by 0x81,0x80

        # When total length is greater than 0x80, we have to set the greatest bit and use the
        # rest of this byte to define how many additional bytes are needed to express the total size
        # For example: if total size is 0xFF00FF then the ASN1 header will look like this
        # 0x0 = 0x30
        # 0x1 = 0x83    <- 0x80 || 0x03 for 3 bytes to express EE00FF
        # 0x30 0x83 0xFF 0x00 0xEE <rest of ASN1 data>
        if ($dataLength -ge 0x80) {
            while ($dataLength -ge 1) {$size++; $dataLength /= 256}
        }
        return $size
    }

    [uint64]GetLength() {
        $size = $this.GetDataLength()
        $size += $this.GetHeaderLength($size)
        return $size
    }

    # Build and return the stream
    [byte[]]GetBytes() {
        if ($this.HashAlgorithm -eq 0) {throw 'Must include default hash algorithm'}
        if ($this.EncryptionAlgorithm -eq 0) {throw 'Must include default encryption algorithm'}

        # If there is more than one flag set then you can catch it by using -band (flags - 1)
        if ($this.HashAlgorithm -band ($this.HashAlgorithm - 1)) {
                throw "Invalid flags for default Hash Algorithm: $this.HashAlgorithm"}
        if ($this.EncryptionAlgorithm -band ($this.EncryptionAlgorithm - 1)) {
                throw "Invalid flags for default Encryption Algorithm: $this.EncryptionAlgorithm"}

        # Make sure that Other doesn't contain the default flag
        $this.OtherEncryptionAlgorithms = $this.OtherEncryptionAlgorithms -band (-bnot $this.EncryptionAlgorithm)
        $this.OtherHashAlgorithms = $this.OtherHashAlgorithms -band (-bnot $this.HashAlgorithm)

        $outputArray = $null
        $defaultCrypt = $null
        $dataSize = $this.GetDataLength()

        # pos and headerSize are used synonymously
        $pos = $this.GetHeaderLength($dataSize)
        $outputArray = [byte[]]::new($dataSize + $pos)
        $outputArray[0] = [byte]0x30

        if ($pos -eq 2) {
            $outputArray[1] = [byte]$dataSize
        } else {
            $outputArray[1] = [byte]($pos - 2) -bxor 0x80
            
            $sizeBytes = [bitconverter]::GetBytes($dataSize)
            if ([bitconverter]::IsLittleEndian) {[array]::Reverse($sizeBytes)}

            # We need to skip leading zeros
            $iPos = 0
            # Find the first non-zero byte
            while ($sizeBytes[$iPos] -eq 0) {$iPos++}
            $iPos2 = 2
            # Start at pos 2 and copy elements until end of $sizeBytes
            while ($iPos -lt $sizeBytes.Length) {$outputArray[$iPos2++] = $sizeBytes[$iPos++]}
        }

        # Header is complete, now we can compile the ASN1 data
        $CryptAsn = $Global:CryptAsn
        $HashAsn = $Global:HashAsn

        $defaultCrypt = $CryptAsn[$this.EncryptionAlgorithm]
        $defaultCrypt.CopyTo($outputArray, $pos)
        $pos += $defaultCrypt.Length

        # This clever bit of code was written by bb-froggy (Christoph Hannebauer) https://github.com/bb-froggy
        #     based on the CountFlags function above
        # When I was looking at CountFlags, I thought about attempting this and then talked myself out of it
        # After seeing it in action, I think it makes sense to include it
        $enum = $this.OtherEncryptionAlgorithms
        while ($enum) {
            $enumLast = $enum
            # When you subtract 1 and -band to the original, you retain all flags save for the flag of highest value
            $enum = $enum -band ($enum - 1)
            # Here we use -bxor to extract the one flag we removed in the last step
            $addBytes = $CryptAsn[$enumLast -bxor $enum]
            $addBytes.CopyTo($outputArray, $pos)
            $pos += $addBytes.Length
        }

        $defaultHash = $HashAsn[$this.HashAlgorithm]
        $defaultHash.CopyTo($outputArray, $pos)
        $pos += $defaultHash.Length

        # Again, credit to bb-froggy (Christoph Hannebauer) https://github.com/bb-froggy
        $enum = $this.OtherHashAlgorithms
        while ($enum) {
            $enumLast = $enum
            $enum = $enum -band ($enum - 1)
            $addBytes = $HashAsn[$enumLast -bxor $enum]
            $addBytes.CopyTo($outputArray, $pos)
            $pos += $addBytes.Length
        }

        return $outputArray

    }# End method GetBytes
}# End class ESAlgorithmAsn

###########################  END ESAlgorithmAsn custom class  ###########################


###########################  BEGIN ESConfigSet custom class  ###########################

# We've been unable to reverse this data. So far it's the same 20-byte string for every config entry
# I suspect they could be for Cryptography format as well as security labels
# My limited tests showed that converting from Object[] -> Byte[] -> BigInt[] was slightly faster than using
#     a BigInt construtor to directly convert an Object[]
Set-Variable ESConfigStaticData -Option ReadOnly -value `
        ([bigint][byte[]](0x1,0x0,0x8,0x0,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x6,0x0,0x8,0x0,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x20,0x0,0x8,0x0))

enum ESConfigItemID {
    AsnHashList = 0x02
    SignatureCertHash = 0x09
    NameA = 0x0B
    EncryptionCertHash = 0x22
    NameW = 0x51
}

[Flags()] enum ESConfigOption {
    Default1 = 1
    Default2 = 2
    SendWithMsgs = 4
}


# This class handles a complete configuration set in Outlook's Email Security section
# Each set has a flag for being default so when building the stream, we check for
#     multiple defaults and remove any duplicates

class ESConfigSet {
    [string]$Name = ''
    [ESConfigOption]$Options = [ESConfigOption]::SendWithMsgs
    [ESAlgorithmAsn]$AlgorithmAsn

    # Internal method to update both hash and thumbprint
    # This is wrapped by another hidden method with three overloads, each of which is wrapped by
    #     two public methods for encryption and for signature
    # I really love how this allowed me to have six public functions with minimal redundant code
    hidden [void]UpdateCertValues([string]$thumbprint, [byte[]]$hash, [bool]$isSig, [bool]$Force) {
        # We either need $Force set to true or we check that the certificate exists in the "My" cert store
        if ($Force -or (Test-Path "Cert:\currentuser\my\$thumbprint")) {
            $o = $this.PSObject.Properties

            # Here we set the cert type as a string and use that to generate the return values
            #     for the dynamically added properties
            $certType = if ($isSig) {'Signature'} else {'Encryption'}

            $nameHash = "$certType"+'CertHash'
            $nameTP = "$certType"+'CertThumbprint'
            $nameFunc = 'Set'+"$certType"+'Cert'

            $o.Remove($nameHash)
            $o.Remove($nameTP)

            # Generate the error message used by both properties
            $sbe = [ScriptBlock]::Create('throw ''This property is Read Only. To update the'+`
                    " certificate, use $nameFunc(`$input) instead'")

            # This resolves to the value or $thumbprint so when the scriptblock is passed to the property 'Getter' method
            #     it is passed as a literal string versus linking back to a variable
            # I would have had to dynamically generate the variable name anyway, so this felt more efficient
            $sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("return '$thumbprint'")
            $o.Add([PSScriptProperty]::New($nameTP, $sb, $sbe))
            $hashString = ([bitconverter]::ToString($hash)).Replace('-',',0x')
            $sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("return ([byte[]](@(0x$hashString)))")
            $o.Add([PSScriptProperty]::New($nameHash, $sb, $sbe))
        } else {
            # Force flag was not set and cert was not found
            throw "Unable to find $thumbprint in 'My' certificate store`r`n"+`
            "Set to skip this check"
        }
    }

    hidden [void]SetCert([string]$thumbprint, [bool]$isSig, [bool]$Force) {
        if ($thumbprint.Length -ne 40) {throw "Bad length: $($thumbprint.Length). Expected 40"}
        $hash = tp2Hash $thumbprint
        $this.UpdateCertValues($thumbprint, $hash, $isSig, $Force)
    }

    hidden [void]SetCert([byte[]]$hash, [bool]$isSig, [bool]$Force) {
        if ($hash.Length -ne 20) {throw "Bad length: $($hash.Length). Expected 20"}
        $thumbprint = ([bitconverter]::ToString($hash)).Replace('-','')
        $this.UpdateCertValues($thumbprint, $hash, $isSig, $Force)
    }

    hidden [void]SetCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert, [bool]$isSig, [bool]$Force) {
        $this.UpdateCertValues($cert.Thumbprint, $cert.GetCertHash(), $isSig, $Force)
    }

    ESConfigSet([string]$name) {
        $this.Name = $name
        $this.Options = [ESConfigOption]::SendWithMsgs
    }

    ESConfigSet() {
        $this.Name = 'Default Settings'
        $this.Options = [ESConfigOption]::SendWithMsgs
    }

    # Create a new configset object and import the blob
    ESConfigSet([byte[]]$blob) {
        # First we check for the expected static data
        # If we figure out what this data means and/or how to parse it, this will need to be reworked
        $staticData = [bigint]([byte[]]($blob[0..19]))
        if ($staticData -ne $Global:ESConfigStaticData) {
            $sExpected = [bitconverter]::ToString($Global:ESConfigStaticData.ToByteArray())
            $sReceived = [bitconverter]::ToString($staticData.ToByteArray())
            throw ((
                'Unexpected staticData',
                "Expected $sExpected",
                "Received $sReceived") -join "`n")
        }

        # Import options flags
        $this.Options = [bitconverter]::ToUint32($blob, 20)

        # Now begin stepping through the data from pos 24
        # These config items should work in any order but I haven't tested this
        $pos = 24
        while ($pos -lt $blob.length) {
            [ESConfigItemID]$id = [bitconverter]::ToUint16($blob, $pos)
            $itemSize = [bitconverter]::ToUint16($blob, $pos + 2)
            $end = $pos + $itemSize - 1
            $bData = $blob[($pos + 4)..$end]
            switch ($id) {
                ([ESConfigItemID]::NameW) {
                    if ($this.Name.Length -eq 0) {
                        # End is Length - 1 and then - 2 more for the unicode null terminator
                        $this.Name = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bData[0..($bData.Length - 3)])
                    }
                }
                ([ESConfigItemID]::NameA) {
                    if ($this.Name.Length -eq 0) {
                        # Strip the trailing null terminator
                        $this.Name = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bData[0..($bData.Length - 2)])
                    }
                }
                ([ESConfigItemID]::EncryptionCertHash) {
                    if ($bData.Length -ne 0x14) {throw "Invalid hash size: $($bData.Length), expected 20"}
                    $thumbprint = ([bitconverter]::ToString($bData)).Replace('-','')
                    $this.UpdateCertValues($thumbprint, $bData, $false, $true)
                }
                ([ESConfigItemID]::SignatureCertHash) {
                    if ($bData.Length -ne 0x14) {throw "Invalid hash size: $($bData.Length), expected 20"}
                    $thumbprint = ([bitconverter]::ToString($bData)).Replace('-','')
                    $this.UpdateCertValues($thumbprint, $bData, $true, $true)
                }
                ([ESConfigItemID]::AsnHashList) {
                    $this.AlgorithmAsn = [ESAlgorithmAsn]::New($bData)
                }
            }
            $pos = $end + 1
        }
    }# End ESConfigSet($blob) constructor

    # Six Certifiate function overloads to wrap three common hidden methods
    [void]SetSignatureCert([string]$thumbprint) {$this.SetCert($thumbprint, $true, $false)}
    [void]SetSignatureCert([string]$thumbprint, $Force) {$this.SetCert($thumbprint, $true, $Force)}
    [void]SetSignatureCert([byte[]]$hash) {$this.SetCert($hash, $true, $false)}
    [void]SetSignatureCert([byte[]]$hash, $Force) {$this.SetCert($hash, $true, $Force)}
    [void]SetSignatureCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert) {
            $this.SetCert($cert, $true, $false)}
    [void]SetSignatureCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert, $Force) {
            $this.SetCert($cert, $true, $Force)}
    [void]SetEncryptionCert([string]$thumbprint) {$this.SetCert($thumbprint, $false, $false)}
    [void]SetEncryptionCert([string]$thumbprint, $Force) {$this.SetCert($thumbprint, $false, $Force)}
    [void]SetEncryptionCert([byte[]]$hash) {$this.SetCert($hash, $false, $false)}
    [void]SetEncryptionCert([byte[]]$hash, $Force) {$this.SetCert($hash, $false, $Force)}
    [void]SetEncryptionCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert) {
            $this.SetCert($cert, $false, $false)}
    [void]SetEncryptionCert([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$cert, $Force) {
            $this.SetCert($cert, $false, $Force)}


    [uint64]GetLength() {
        # First check that we have a name as well as thumbprints for certificates
        # This is efficient because PS will short circuit with the first true statement
        if (($this.Name.Length -eq 0) -or
                ($this.EncryptionCertHash.Length -eq 0) -or
                ($this.SignatureCertHash.Length -eq 0) -or
                ($this.AlgorithmAsn.Length -eq 0)) {
            return 0
        }

        # $size = 20    #$staticData.Length
        # $size += 24   #20 byte Encryption hash plus its header
        # $size += 24   #20 byte Signature hash plus its header
        # $size += 4    #Uint32 for options flags
        # $size += 4    #Header for unicode name
        # $size += 4    #Header for ASCII name
        # $size += 4    #ASN1 data header

        [uint64]$size = 84

        # Since we need the name in ASCII as well as Unicode and both null-terminated
        #    we can simply multiply the length with terminator * 3
        $size += ($this.Name.Length + 1) * 3

        $size += $this.AlgorithmAsn.GetLength()

        return $size
    }

    [byte[]]GetBytes() {
        # Calculate Total size and create a byte array of that size
        [uint64]$size = $this.GetLength()
        if ($size -eq 0) {
            if ($this.Name.Length -eq 0) {throw 'Name not set'}
            if ($this.EncryptionCertHash.Length -eq 0) {throw 'Encryption certificate not configured'}
            if ($this.SignatureCertHash.Length -eq 0) {throw 'Signature certificate not configured'}
            if ($this.AlgorithmAsn.Length -eq 0) {throw 'Algorithms object is missing'}
        }

        $outputArray = [byte[]]::New($size)

        # Insert static data
        $Global:ESConfigstaticData.ToByteArray().CopyTo($outputArray, 0)

        # Insert options flags
        ([bitconverter]::GetBytes([uint16]($this.Options))).CopyTo($outputArray, 20)
        $pos = 24

        # This looks overly complicated but it reduced many lines of redundant code
        # For each item in this list...
        foreach ($entryID in @(
                    [ESConfigItemID]::NameW,
                    [ESConfigItemID]::NameA,
                    [ESConfigItemID]::EncryptionCertHash,
                    [ESConfigItemID]::SignatureCertHash,
                    [ESConfigItemID]::AsnHashList)) {
            # ... execute the following block
            ([bitconverter]::GetBytes([uint16]$entryID)).CopyTo($outputArray, $pos)
            $addBytes = switch ($entryID) {
                ([ESConfigItemID]::NameW) {([Text.Encoding]::Unicode).GetBytes($this.Name + "`0")}
                ([ESConfigItemID]::NameA) {([Text.Encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($this.Name + "`0")}
                ([ESConfigItemID]::EncryptionCertHash) {$this.EncryptionCertHash}
                ([ESConfigItemID]::SignatureCertHash) {$this.SignatureCertHash}
                ([ESConfigItemID]::AsnHashList) {$this.AlgorithmAsn.GetBytes()}
            }
            ([bitconverter]::GetBytes([uint16]($addBytes.Length + 4))).CopyTo($outputArray, $pos + 2)
            $pos += 4
            $addBytes.CopyTo($outputArray, $pos)
            $pos += $addBytes.Length
        }
        return $outputArray
    }
}# End class ESConfigSet

###########################  END ESConfigSet custom class  ###########################


###########################  BEGIN ESConfig custom class  ###########################


class ESConfig {
    [ESConfigSet[]]$Entries

    # I didn't see a reason to make these visible
    # These can still be called explicitly, they just don't show in the autocomplete list or when using Get-Member
    # This method ensures that only one config set has the default flag and removes any duplicates beyond first found
    hidden [void]ValidateDefault() {
        if ($this.Entries.Count -gt 1) {
            # I'm not able to have the 2 defaults separated to different config sets on my system
            #     but it might be possible on someone else's systems so we run this once for each default flag
            foreach ($config in @([ESConfigOption]::Default1, [ESConfigOption]::Default2)) {
                # Iterate entries and verify that only one is default
                $default = ''
                foreach ($entry in $this.Entries) {
                    if ($entry.Options -band $config) {
                        if ($default) {
                            Write-Host "Removing $config flag from '$($entry.Name)' because '$default' is already default"
                            $entry.Options = $entry.Options -band ( -bnot $config)
                        } else {
                            $default = $entry.Name
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($default -eq '') {
                    Write-Host "Setting '$($this.Entries[0].Name)' as default"
                    $this.Entries[0].Options = $this.Entries[0].Options -bor $config
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # This tries to intelligently rename any duplicate names
    hidden [void]ValidateNames() {
        if ($this.Entries.Count -gt 1) {
            $bFound = $true
            while ($bFound) {
                $bFound = $false
                for ($i1 = 0; $i1 -lt $this.Entries.Count - 1; $i1++) {
                    $number = 2
                    for ($i2 = $i1 + 1; $i2 -lt $this.Entries.Count; $i2++) {
                        if ($this.Entries[$i1].Name -eq $this.Entries[$i2].Name) {
                            $bFound = $true
                            $this.Entries[$i2].Name += " ($number)"
                            $number++
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # If constructed with no params, generate some default settings
    ESConfig() {
        $this.Entries.Add([ESConfigSet]::New('Default Settings'))
        $this.Entries[0].Options = $this.Entries[0].Options -bor
                [ESConfigOption]::Default1 -bor [ESConfigOption]::Default2
    }

    # Construct a new object and import everything from the blob
    ESConfig( [byte[]]$colBlob ) {
        # Do some basic error checking
        $pos = 0
        $numEntries = [bitconverter]::ToUint32($colBlob, 0)

        # Check that the total size is at least 4 + 0x10 * number of entries
        if ($colBlob.Length -lt (4 + ($numEntries * 0x10))) {
                throw 'Data too short: $($colBlob.Length), expected miminum $(4 + ($numEntries * 0x10))'}

        # Skip to the last entry, add offset + size and verify it matches the size of the blob
        $pos = (($numEntries - 1) * 0x10) + 4
        $end = [bitconverter]::ToUint64($colBlob, $pos) + [bitconverter]::ToUint64($colBlob, $pos + 8)
        if ($end -ne $colBlob.Length) {
            if ($end -ge $colBlob.Length) {
                throw 'Settings data appears to be corrupted (Data offset is beyond end of data)'
            } else {
                # Sometimes Outlook seems to add padding after the end so we'll verify that it's all zeros
                foreach ($byte in $colblob[$end..($colBlob.Length - 1)]) {
                    if ($byte -ne 0) {throw 'Settings appear to be corrupted (Data beyond last offset)'}
                }
            }
        }

        # import each settings entry
        $this.Entries = [ESConfigSet[]]::new($numEntries)
        for ($i = 0;$i -lt $numEntries;$i++) {
            $pos = 4 + ($i * 0x10)
            $entrySize = [bitconverter]::ToUint64($colBlob, $pos)
            $offset = [bitconverter]::ToUint64($colBlob, $pos + 8)
            [byte[]]$blob = $colBlob[($offset)..($offset + $entrySize - 1)]
            $this.Entries[$i] = [ESConfigSet]::new($blob)
        }

        $this.ValidateDefault()
        $this.ValidateNames()
    }

    # Adds a new config set
    [void]AddEntry([ESConfigSet]$set) {
        $this.Entries = $this.Entries + $set
        $this.ValidateDefault()
        $this.ValidateNames()
    }

    # The default collection is fixed size so we have to generate a new one
    [void]RemoveEntry([uint32]$index) {
        $newArray = [ESConfigSet[]]::new($this.Entries.Count - 1)
        $nextIndex = 0
        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $this.Entries.Count; $i++) {
            if ($i -ne $index) {$newArray[$nextIndex] = $this.Entries[$i]}
        }
        $this.Entries = $newArray
        $this.ValidateDefault()
        $this.ValidateNames()
    }

    [void]SetDefaultEntry([int]$index) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $this.Entries.Count; $i++) {
            if ($i -eq $index) {
                $this.Entries[$i].Options = $this.Entries[$i].Options -bor
                        [ESConfigOption]::Default1 -bor [ESConfigOption]::Default2
            } else {
                $this.Entries[$i].Options = $this.Entries[$i].Options -band ( -bnot
                        ([ESConfigOption]::Default1 -bor [ESConfigOption]::Default2))
            }
        }
    }

    [void]SetDefaultEntry([string]$name) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $this.Entries.Count; $i++) {
            if ($name -eq $this.Entries[$i].Name) {
                $this.SetDefaultEntry([uint32]$i)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    [uint64]GetLength() {
        [uint64]$Size = (($this.Entries.Count * 0x10) + 4)
        foreach ($entry in $this.Entries) {$size += $entry.GetLength()}
        return $Size
    }

    [byte[]]GetBytes() {
        $this.ValidateDefault()
        $this.ValidateNames()

        $outputArray = [byte[]]::New($this.GetLength())
        ([bitconverter]::GetBytes([uint32]$this.Entries.Count)).CopyTo($outputArray, 0)

        # We need to step back and forth so we need to keep track of data position as well as toc position
        $tocPos = 4
        [uint64]$dataPos = (($this.Entries.Count * 0x10) + 4)

        # Add each settings entry and update the TOC
        foreach ($entry in $this.Entries) {
            $curBlob = $entry.GetBytes()
            ([bitconverter]::GetBytes([uint64]$curBlob.Length)).CopyTo($outputArray, $tocPos)
            $tocPos += 8
            ([bitconverter]::GetBytes($dataPos)).CopyTo($outputArray, $tocPos)
            $tocPos += 8
            $curBlob.CopyTo($outputArray, $dataPos)
            $dataPos += $curBlob.Length
        }
        return $outputArray
    }

}# End class ESConfig

###########################  BEGIN ESConfig custom class  ###########################


###########################  BEGIN Top level functions  ###########################

function Get-OutlookProfileList() {
    return (gi HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\).GetSubKeyNames()
}

function Get-OutlookESConfig([string]$profileName) {
    $blob = (gp "HKCU:\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\$profileName\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e" -Name 11020355).11020355
    return [ESConfig]::New($blob)
}

function Set-OutlookESConfig([string]$profileName, [ESConfig]$ESConfig, [switch]$noBackup) {
    $key = "HKCU:\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\$profileName\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e"

    $dest = Get-ItemProperty "$key" -Name 11020355 -EA Silent

    if ($dest) {
        if (! $noBackup) {
            rp "$key" -Name 11020355.bak -EA Silent
            Copy-ItemProperty "$key" -Name 11020355 -Dest 11020355.bak
        }
        sp -Path "$path" -Name "$name" -Value $ESConfig.GetBytes()
    } else {
        New-ItemProperty -Path "$key" -Name 11020355 -Value $ESConfig.GetBytes() -PropertyType 'Binary' -EA Silent -OutVariable null
    }
}

###########################  END Top level functions  ###########################
```

Comment: Updated code, performance updates, bug fixes, updated comments